# escape velocity robot behavior move_base

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, global-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a small doubt regarding the robot's behavior when escape velocity (`escape_vel`) is given to it. When the robot is going in the backward direction (escape_vel : -0.2) to escape from a stuck situation, does the `move_base` consider that there might be an obstacle behind it by looking at the costmap? In my case, it does not care if there is an obstacle behind it or not and it keeps on going in the backward direction and hits the obstacle although the obstacles are present in the costmap.

Thanks in advance.
Naman Kumar

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217043/escape-velocity-robot-behavior-move_base/) by [Naman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11186/naman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1464 on 2015-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems that this behavior is implemented intentionally.

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/jade-devel/base_local_planner/src/trajectory_planner.cpp#L864

But it is unclear the reasoning behind this and seems that code segment is there from more than 7 years and unchanged.

I think this behavior should be at least made configurable so users could choose whether to back up without considering obstacles or not.

---

Originally posted by [AravindaDP](https://answers.ros.org/users/27826/aravindadp/) with karma: 36 on 2016-08-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-24**:
Would be nice to include a link to your Github issue: [ros-planning/navigation#516](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/issues/516).